# KDE PLASMA: Slow login to desktop?

Tags: arch-linux, kde, kde-plasma-5, kde-plasma-workspace

I'm a new kde user so i hope anyone helps me.

My problem is, session starts very slow i don't know why ??

*I have a lenovo core i5 , 8 gb ram ,hyperX ssd , and i'm installing Antergos with Kde Plasma desktop*

**Systemd output is so perfect:**

> Startup finished in 4.904s (kernel) + 1.485s (userspace) = 6.389s

On *Desktop session*:

1. **Default leave** is **Turn off computer**
2. **on Login** is **Start with an empty session**

*Polkit Status:*

> polkit.service  Active: active (running)

so any suggestion please.

Thanks you all.

Answer (score 2):

I had to unplug the HDMI and kde plasma 5.10.2 login with arch linux took only 4 seconds. With HDMI plugged in, login took 23 seconds. This is the only answer I have found to date.

Comment: I have the same issue with HDMI in Kubuntu 18.04.